The fastest MOD algorithm in C++ for extremely large uint_64_t numbers stored in an array
I am working with extremely large numbers and would like to verify my Karatsuba multiplication result ((2^136279841)-1)^2 which needs (532 344 * _m256i_epi64)^2 i.e. 4,258,752 uint64_t to store the result.
I stored all required data arrays in a preallocated memory:
size_t num_bits = 136279841;
size_t num_uint64 = (num_bits + 255) / 256 * 4;
size_t n = num_uint64;

// Correct calculation for First_256_offset
size_t First_256_offset = (GB * 0x40000000ULL) - ((2ULL + 1ULL) * num_uint64 * sizeof(uint64_t));

constexpr size_t GB = 3;
static const SIZE_T giga = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
static const SIZE_T size = GB * giga;
uint64_t* ARRAY = static_cast<uint64_t*>(VirtualAlloc(NULL, size, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE));

uint64_t* number = ARRAY + First_256_offset / sizeof(uint64_t);

 // Store the number (2^136279841)-1) using _mm256_maskstore_epi64 in a loop
 __m256i ones = _mm256_set1_epi64x(-1);
 size_t i = 0;
 for (; i < (num_uint64 - 4); i += 4) {
     _mm256_store_si256((__m256i*) & number[i], ones);
 }

_mm256_maskstore_epi64((long long int*) & number[i], _mm256_setr_epi64x(-1, -1, -1, -1), _mm256_setr_epi64x(0x1111111111111111, 0x0000000000000001LL, 0x0, 0x0));

I need to calculate the MOD (A, B) where A, multiplication result which takes about 3 minutes on my laptop, is stored from ARRAY and B is the number in the code. The memory space above A and below First_256_offset is used as temporary space for Karatsuba multiplication. In the MOD (A, B) result, I may use the space below First_256_offset.
I need to avoid using any external libraries, vector, string or memalloc functions.
P.S. Note that I am using uint64_t operation in my C++ Karatsuba program because _m256i can handle int64_t only and I need to work with uint64_t data.

Division and mod are both very expensive operations. Why can't you create the target result of (2^N-1)^2 = 2^(2N) + 1 - 2^(N+1) by an alternative bitwise method and then compare for equality?

Can you explain to me how to use  bitwise method? Link to the algoritm would be appreciated.

From the structure of the binary representation it is obviously (N-1) 1's N 0's 1. The first few being 1,9, 49, 225, 961 or in binary 1, 1001, 110001, 11100001, 1111000001 etc.

"B is the number in the code" - what number? there's no variable named B and I don't see any modulo in the code either

The "B" number is defined here:
uint64_t* number = ARRAY + First_256_offset / sizeof(uint64_t);
I am just asking for MOD algorithm, I didn't put here the main program for Karatsuba multiplication.
